# Jupyter notebook not printing underscores?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook refuses to print underscores in strings.

```
task_line = '### [TASK] Building the app for wonders \n'
task_pattern = "# [TASK]"

task_name = task_line.split(task_pattern)[-1].strip()
task_name.replace(" ", "_")
```

Prints: `'Building_the_app_for_wonders'`

However, a stripped down example does the replace correctly:

```
task_name = 'Building the app for wonders' 
task_name.replace(" ", "_")
```

Prints: `'Building_the_app_for_wonders'`

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with Jupyter notebook but with the way the underscore is rendered in the example. The browser decided not to show the underscore for that particular resolution. :)

[image]

Zooming in show that it's just a presentation problem.

[image]