# Getting underscore in Jupyter notebook equation (mathml)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, equation, mathml

Not sure if the answer here [Jupyter notebook not printing underscores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276411/jupyter-notebook-not-printing-underscores) is related:

> The problem is not with Jupyter notebook but with the way the underscore is rendered in the example. The browser decided not to show the underscore for that particular resolution

... but here it goes: I try to enter the equation `$$ \mathtt{A\_b} = \frac{A}{b} $$` in a Markdown cell in Jupyter notebook; and the rendering I get is this:

[image: underscore_rendering_jupyter_markdown]

Don't know about you, but that looks like a dash/minus sign to me, not like an underscore.

So, how can I get a proper underline rendered in an equation in Jupyter notebook Markdown (where the equation is written as Latex, but rendered as MathML)?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround - but I'd still love to hear a proper answer by someone who knows better ...

In the meantime - simply don't include the underscore inside `\mathtt`; that is, use:

```
$$ \mathtt{A}\_\mathtt{b} = \frac{A}{b} $$
```

... which results with:

[image: rendering ok underscore in equation]